# UWP Control panel app settings

Tags: c#, windows, uwp

If i declared a permission in application manifest(eg. microphone) is there a way to check if the user has enabled this permission and to change permission if user agrees to have permission changed?

This is for a UWP application written in C# to allow cortana to interact with application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to check if the user has enabled this permission?

Call [MediaCapture.InitializeAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.capture.mediacapture.initializeasync) method in a try-catch block, specify you want to initialize microphone in the `MediaCaptureInitializationSettings` parameter. If it is the first time use of this API, it will launch a consent prompt to get the user's permission for the app to access the microphone. If user has already refused to grant permission, you get an exception.

> Can I Change permission if user agrees to have permission changed?

No. It is the user that takes full control over this, there is no API to change the permission. Just imagine how many apps will secretly grant themselves access without user's consent if such API exists.

However, when detecting the permission is somehow turned off, you can launch the `Settings` app to the `Privacy -> Microphone` page so user can easily grant the permission there. Again, user takes full control over this.

```
await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("ms-settings:privacy-microphone"));
```